# Progress indicator not bring to front view

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mbprogresshud

ProgressIndicator (MTMProgressHub) when bring to Front its not appears

```
    hud = new MTMBProgressHUD (View);
    View.BringSubviewToFront (hud);
    View.AddSubview (hud);
    hud.Show (true);
```

Please find the below Image[image]

As showing in image the progress indicator is back side of buttons (Registration Login Contact Us)..

```
    public LoginViewController(){

        hud = new MTMBProgressHUD (View);
        View.BringSubviewToFront (hud);
        View.AddSubview (hud);
        hud.Show (true);
```

}

unable to push it to front.

Comment: alternate this line 1.  View.AddSubview (hud); 2. View.BringSubviewToFront (hud);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bring a view to front only when it is added to a parent view.
Here you called `BringSubviewToFront` before adding it to the view.

Change that to:

```
hud = new MTMBProgressHUD (View);
View.AddSubview (hud);
View.BringSubviewToFront (hud);
hud.Show (true);
```